# Using WordPress Content Item as a Taxonomy

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way (or a plugin) to make a given content type in WordPress (i.e. posts, pages, media, custom post types) act as a taxonomy? I basically want to setup a one-to-many relationship of one item in a given post type to many items of a different type.

So basically, I have a custom post type, call it Authors. I want to use a Post Type rather than a taxonomy because I need a lot more meta data than a taxonomy allows.

I then have another custom post type called Books.

Is there a way to put a box similar to the Categories or Tags metaboxes on the Author write page that display a list of all the books. I can then choose from a list of all the books, thus creating a relationship.

If this doesn't already exist, I guess I'll write a plugin for it. I thought I'd give this a try first, just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered adding new meta fields to a custom taxonomy? Unfortunately, you ned to either create a new table for the meta storage or use wp_options, but it does work and is relatively future-friendly. Remember to start your option names with an underscore, though.

http://www.strangework.com/2010/07/01/how-to-save-taxonomy-meta-data-as-an-options-array-in-wordpress/

Comment: I've considered it... The problem there is each content type is separate and equal to all the others. I'd rather not limit myself to a taxonomy when it really should be a content type. Thanks for the link though, it's an interesting approach that I'm sure I'll be able to use at some point.